# Maven unit testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, maven

When unit testing in a multi module maven project do you run the lifecycle face: test. Or should I use the IntelliJ IDEA testing? Maybe I am wrong but I can't see any option to where you can see red/green as you do in non-maven projects. What is preffered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and should, be using both forms of testing. When you are doing your development, I would run the tests in your IDE because it's convenient. However, when you're done development and check it your code, you should run `maven test` to ensure every test still passes.

The real perk of having Maven run your tests, is that you can run them automatically on a continuous integration server. Depending on what CI server you use, it might have a user interface that shows you if you had any test fail in a nice pretty way.

Answer (score 1):

It does not really change something, here, that you run a multi-module project. The phases that are executed mainly depends on your packaging type since it defines the lifecycle of your build.

Now, remember that when you choose a phase, Maven will execute all the pre-necessary phases before the one you chose plus the one you chose of course. So for example, if you are running a jar build with phase test, you will have the following phases: process-resources, compile, process-test-resources, test-compile and test (by default, at least).

You can also run the test from your IDE, and the choice is a question of preference and what is easiest for you to use. I prefer the IDE way but any choice is fine.

Answer (score 1):

For the individual, it doesn't matter. Let the individual run the tests in whatever way works best for them.

However, you'll *definitely* want to run the maven test lifecycle phase as part of your CI/Release/etc build process no matter what (even if everyone on the team wants to use their IDE)